# Java and programmatically importing a csv into an SQLite3 table

Tags: java, import, sqlite

In Java how do I programmatically import a `csv` text file into a table of an `SQLite3` database? Can this even be done with `SQLite3`'s `.import`, for example `IMPORT myFile myTable`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you cannot execute the 'import' statement through JDBC, what you can do is to either use command line through Runtime.exec or just parse a .csv file within your application, create your sql commands dynamically for each csv line and execute them with JDBC execute().

Comment: A prepared statement will be faster when dealing with many inserts.

Comment: yes, it's not the point here, either way you create an sql command dynamically.